# How do I find and stop the process that is running a server on port 443

Tags: nginx

I get this when I try to start nginx on ubuntu.

`[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)`

How do I find and destroy process responsible?

Comment: (Updated question to specify Ubuntu)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As root:

```
lsof -i :443
```

...should reveal the offending process ID, assuming you have lsof on your operating system.

Comment: I found it was sshd that was the problem. its listening on 443!